# kAudioUnitProperty_MatrixLevels in Swift

Tags: swift, core-audio, unsafemutablepointer

To query a MatrixMixer AudioUnit you do the following:

```
// code from MatrixMixerTest sample project in c++

UInt32 dims[2];
UInt32 theSize =  sizeof(UInt32) * 2;
Float32 *theVols = NULL;
OSStatus result;


ca_require_noerr (result = AudioUnitGetProperty (au, kAudioUnitProperty_MatrixDimensions,   
                        kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, dims, &theSize), home);

theSize = ((dims[0] + 1) * (dims[1] + 1)) * sizeof(Float32);

theVols = static_cast<Float32*> (malloc (theSize));

ca_require_noerr (result = AudioUnitGetProperty (au, kAudioUnitProperty_MatrixLevels,   
                        kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, theVols, &theSize), home);
```

The return value on `AudioUnitGetProperty` for the `kAudioUnitProperty_MatrixLevels` is (defined in the documentation and in the sample code) a Float32.

I am trying to find the matrix levels in swift and can get the matrix dimensions without an issue. But I am not sure how to create an empty array of Float32 elements that is a `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>`. Here's what I have tried without success:

```
var size = ((dims[0] + 1) * (dims[1] + 1)) * UInt32(sizeof(Float32))
var vols = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float32>.alloc(Int(size))
```

In the MatrixMixerTest the array is used like: `theVols[0]`

Comment: What does "without success" mean, exactly?

Comment: I am unable to use `vols` as an array, it crashes with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

Comment: Is the index you're trying to access within the bounds of the array?

Comment: Yes. The array should be 7 long. I am trying to just access the first element.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal runnable example for us to work with?

Comment: Yeah, it may take me a little while to make up a project that uses the minimum parts. How do I attach a project file on stackoverflow? Or should I just put it on github and share that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117020/discussion-between-amomchilov-and-gwrodriguez).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May need to be modified depending on how you converted other parts, 
but the last part of your C++ code can be written in Swift like this:

```
    theSize = ((dims[0] + 1) * (dims[1] + 1)) * UInt32(sizeof(Float32))

    var theVols: [Float32] = Array(count: Int(theSize)/sizeof(Float32), repeatedValue: 0)

    result = AudioUnitGetProperty(au, kAudioUnitProperty_MatrixLevels,
            kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &theVols, &theSize)
    guard result == noErr else {
        //...
        fatalError()
    }
```

When a C-function based API is claiming a `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>`, you just need an `Array` variable of an arbitrary type, and pass it as inout parameter.